# When i use the export excel laravel, the app no continues?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

This is my code, $infoNotificacion[1] is a excel but i need export and continues:

```
$all=array("changes"=>$changes,"noti"=>$noti,"infoNotification"=>$infoNotification[0]);
    $infoNotification[1]->export('xlsx');
    return view('sendEmail')->with('htmls',$all);
```

But the important line is the second because I need return the view but i don't know.

please help me.

Comment: What is the error? Does it work if you use a `dd("X")` after first line?

Comment: When the app just export the xlsx and don't return the view